# How to map an array of strings into a new array of strings?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write some PowerShell code that takes an array of suffixes and builds a new array with an inputted string prefixed to those suffixes.

How can I do something like C#'s Map or aggregation code to build a new list based off the original list?

In the below powershell ...

```
$workspaceName = "test"
$deleteableItemSuffixes = @("-api","-asp","-appi")
$deleteableItemNames = ???
```

I want the resulting array to be `["test-api", "test-asp", "test-appi"]`, for example.

Comment: Something like `$deleteableItemNames = $deleteableItemSuffixes | ForEach-Object { '{0}{1}' -f $workspaceName, $_ }` would do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`-replace` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) allows for a concise and efficient solution for *string* arrays:

```sh
# Returns array @('test-api', 'test-asp', 'test-appi')
"-api", "-asp", "-appi" -replace '^', 'test'
```

- `-replace` is [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based and accepts arrays as input, in which case the operation is performed on each element.
- `^` matches the position at the beginning of the string, at which the substitution string, `'test'` is inserted, in effect prepending that string to each array element (by contrast, `$` matches the *end* of each string and can be used to *append* a value).

---

For other data types and if you need more flexibility, you can use the [`.ForEach()` array method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#foreach) (which, in the case of a collection that is already in memory, is faster than the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) *cmdlet*):

```sh
("-api", "-asp", "-appi").ForEach({ 'test' + $_ })
```

- Strictly speaking, what `.ForEach()` returns isn't a .NET *array*, but a collection of type `[System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[psobject]]`, but the difference usually doesn't matter in PowerShell.
- If you do need an actual array, you can simply *cast* the result:

  ```sh
  # Use the appropriate data type, or simply [array] for an [object[]] array.
  [string[]] ("-api", "-asp", "-appi").ForEach({ 'test' + $_ })
  ```